# Can't expose port with podman

Tags: networking, podman

I am trying to walk through a tutorial that brings up an application in a docker/podman container instance.

I have attempted to use -p port:port and --expose port but neither seems to work.

I've ensured that I see the port in a listen state with ss -an.

I've made sure there isn't anything else trying to bind to that port.

No matter what I do, I can never hit localhost:port or ip_address:port.

I feel like I am fundamentally missing something but don't know where to look next.

Any suggestions for things to try or documentation to review would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Shawn

Comment: It appears this is working as documented with Docker using docker-compose. I'll need to try again with podman and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expose: ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897260/what-does-podman-run-expose-do))

> Expose tells Podman that the container requests that port be open, but
> does not forward it. All exposed ports will be forwarded to random
> ports on the host if and only if --publish-all is also specified

As per Redhat documentation for Containerfile,

> EXPOSE indicates that the container listens on the specified network
> port at runtime. ***The EXPOSE instruction defines metadata only; it does
> not make ports accessible from the host***. The -p option in the podman
> run command exposes container ports from the host.

To specify Port Number,

> The -p option in the podman run command exposes container ports from
> the host.

**Example:**

```
podman run -d -p 8080:80 --name httpd-basic quay.io/httpd-parent:2.4
```

In above example, Port # 80 is the port number which Container listens/exposes and we can access this from outside the container via Port # 8080

Comment: Thank You @vasanth subramanian. I was doing a couple of things that were out of bounds. First, I was  trying to expose ports < 1024.


Second, I was not passing in the correct params to the container that was running the web interface and the node process was aborting which is why I wasn't getting the ui.